# Filling in rows of a column based on a unique ID in another column

Tags: r

I have a large data frame with the following layout:

```
Unique_ID      Year
1404H_1        2004
1404H_2        2004
0696H_1         
0696H_2
2512K_1        2012
2512K_2        2012
```

I have isolated the Unique_ID's with missing Year data but I would like to write a code which can fill them in e.g. if the unique_ID contains '0696H' fill 'Year' with '1996'.

I cannot base it on finding NA's in the Year column as there are multiple unique_ID's which I need to fill in with different years.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `dat` is the dataset

```
 dat$Year[grep("^0696H", dat$Unique_ID)] <- 1996
  dat
  #Unique_ID Year
  #1             NA
  #2   1404H_1 2004
  #3   1404H_2 2004
  #4   0696H_1 1996
  #5   0696H_2 1996
  #6   2512K_1 2012
  #7   2512K_2 2012
```